# Is CORS stopping my AJAX calls from working?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm porting a web app to Android (AppInventor AI2 created) to run in a WebViewer component.

I've got most things working but my AJAX calls to the API scripts on my webserver return null.

My guess is that the server is returning null because the origin of the request is an AJAX call from a standalone web page on my local machine (during dev) or a mobile device rather than coming from a page hosted on the same domain.

A bit of Googling around has turned up a lot of mentions of CORS...

Is this what is causing my problems?

If I call the api URL (it's a PHP script on my server that returns XML) direct from my browser I get the correct data returned.

I also have the same code running as part of the web app and that works fine.

The problem only seems to be when I am calling the HTML and JavaScript files from a local directory on my machine. (All other JavaScript function are working correctly, it's just those with AJAX calls that are getting null responses from the webserver that are causing me problems.

I have tried uploading the JS file to my webserver and calling that from the html but that didn't work either (It was a long shot as I guess the AJAX call is still actually being made from the local html file essentially).

Here is a full setup that can be used to test...

HTML file with JavaScript included:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test BBP App AJAX Error</title>

<script>
function getDataViaAJAX(url, callback) {

    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            alert("ready state of ajax changed to 4");
            alert("request/data responseText=" + request.responseText);
            alert("request=" + request);
//          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
        }
    };
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}

function doTheLocalTest() {
    getDataViaAJAX("./sample.xml", function (data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        alert("Response is: '"+xml+"'")
    });
}
function doTheWebTest() {
    getDataViaAJAX("http://www.bluebadgeparking.com/sample.xml", function (data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        alert("Response is: '"+xml+"'")
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Click To Get XML from a local file" onClick="doTheLocalTest();">
<br />
<input type="button" value="Click To Get XML from the web" onClick="doTheWebTest();">
</body>
</html>
```

And a sample XML content (sample.xml):

```
<markers>
<marker id="1" descr="Whitefriars Street: One way street. Space on left." lat="51.5140241200000" lng="-0.1074814800000"/>
<marker id="1898" descr="Southern General Hospital, Surgical / Orthopaedic 1 Bay" lat="55.8635700800000" lng="-4.3390578030000"/>
</markers>
```

Save those to a local directory and try it.

When reading the XML from a local file it works, when loading the file from my webserver it fails with an empty response being returned.

(As an aside, I'm assuming I would have the same issues if I was developing a FireFox add-on that pulled data in via AJAX from my web server - something else I've been considering recently...)

Comment: Are you running off file: protocol or http: //localhost?

Comment: That would work for my development, but not really when it gets bundled into the Android app - surely then I'd have to bundle a webserver into the App.. no?

Comment: What does the JavaScript error console say? (Presumably there is a way to get a view on it for an Android app).

Comment: No way to see the JavaScript console within Android from what I can tell, however I'm just developing locally at the moment with the files stored on my PC as well. The JavaScript console for FireFox on the PC just reports that the variable that the returned XML is assigned to is null. I've also added a bunch of alerts to see whats happening and the AJAX request returns a status 4 OK, but checking immediately after that I can see that the response was empty.

Comment: @epascarello I'm just loading the html via file protocol. Why would that make a difference? (Also see the additions to the question - when supplying a local file to the AJAX call it works.. pointing even more at this being a 'cross-domain' - or at least not-the-same-domain - issue.

Comment: Browsers have different security levels based on where it loads. file is locked down and you can not do as much. There are flags you can set, but it is always better to run off a local server.

Comment: @epascarello Ultimately this will be a local html (and JS) file that will be bundled in an Android app. The file will be loaded via file protocol into the apps browser component so I need a way for the AJAX call to work in that scenario.

Comment: I do not do Android development so I can not help you there.

Comment: @epascarello I haven't got as far as testing on Android yet.. These are currently just local files being read as files into FireFox (not server by a webserver). (Actually, I have tested on Android in the same way as on the PC - ie loading the files as files into FireFox for Android - I get the same problem on PC and Android so it's not an Android issue). Oh and Chrome and FireFox both behave the same way on both PC and Android.

Comment: Hmmm. I've tried embedding the files into my Android app and guess what - the AJAX calls work perfectly. No changes, but the AJAX calls get the correct XML returned from the web... so it's just the development side of things that's causing me the problem.